# PHP form - uploading an image to place an avatar on a comment feature for news articles

Tags: php, sql, image, file

Trying to make a simple script to comment on a news articles, it's working for the text but I would like the user to be able to submit a image to use as a icon or avatar. This is the form field:

```
             <form action= "../create_comment.php" method="post" name="comments_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
              <label>Name<span>*</span></label>
              <input name="name" type="text" value=" ">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Email<span>*</span></label>
              <input name="email" type="text" value=" ">
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Your Comment<span>*</span></label>
              <textarea name="comment"> </textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
            <label>Add your avatar<span>*</span></label>
            <input name="file" type="file"  />
            <div>
            <input name="storyid" value="192837465" type="hidden">
            <input name="page_path" value="777776" type="hidden">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
          </form>
```

and the form is directing to this script:

```
    <?php
    $formats = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ( $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 90000 && in_array($extension, $formats) ) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            // something went wrong, display the error using; $_FILES["file"]["error"];
        } else {
            if ( !file_exists("avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] ) ) {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            }
        }
    }
    $tempLink = "http://www.website.com/avatars/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $page_path = $_POST['page_path'];
    $con=mysqli_connect
    ("","","","");
     // Check connection
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       }
     $sql="INSERT INTO comments (name, comment, email, storyid, entry_date)
     VALUES
     ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[comment]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[storyid]',now())";
     if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
       {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
       }
    header('Location: http://www.website.com/' . $page_path);
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

The script runs to completion but the image doesn't get saved to:

www.website.com/avatars/

All the other form data inserts into SQL just fine. Only problem is the image. The targeted directory is chmod 0777.

Comment: Have you set form attribute enctype to "multipart/form-data"?

Comment: Put enctype="multipart/form-data in your form tag.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the opening *form* tag in your code

Comment: adding a enctype has worked! I swear some of you guys are mindreaders

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in form html add

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```